# Taking notes for class in Latex, and changing parts of fancy header across include

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am beginning grad school in the fall and I wanted to try and take (or copy over after class) all my notes in `LaTeX`. I wrote a python script that looks at my calendar for all occurrences of classes. Then I generate a file structure for each class and date as follows:

```
root 
  |--- semesterNum\
          |--- class1\
          |      |--- classDay-1\
          |      |      |--- className_date.tex
          |      |      |--- main.tex
          |      | 
          |      |--- ...
          |      |--- classDay-N\
          |      |--- images\
          |      |--- main\
          |             |--- main.tex
          |
          |--- classN\
          |--- main\
                 |--- main.tex
```

In `className_date.tex` is where I will place my actually notes for a given class and date. The `main.tex` below `className_date.tex` is where I can compile my day to day notes.

I keep all my preambles in the `main.tex` files

In the `root/semesterNum/classN/main/main.tex` is where I wanted to compile all the notes from one class

And in `root/semesterNum/main/main.tex` is where I want to compile all my notes from the whole semester for all classes

So to do this I was going to be include each days file into the correct `main.tex` files

My issue is that I have 6 parameters in my tex template that get replaced in my python code they are as follows:

`cName`, `cNum`, `cClass` of `tClass`, `cDate`, and `tName`
 class name, class number (i.e MATH 101), current class number of totals classes, class date, and professor name, respectively

```
\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{l r | l r}
\textbf{Class Name} & cName & \textbf{Class Num} & cNum  \\
\textbf{Page} & \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}& \textbf{Note} & cClass/tClass \\
\textbf{Class Date}& cDate & \textbf{Updated} & \today \\
\textbf{Author} & my name & \textbf{Professor} & tName \\
\end{tabular}}
```

In the `main.tex` for each class date I set the 6 variables. The issue is when I want to include all the notes for one class the current class number of total classes needs to change for each include. but they are set in the level up's preamble, and if I set the variables in the class preamble they won't change for each include.

And when I include all my notes for all classes, the 6 variables need to change for each class and each class date.

I had considered just compiling each set of notes separately then putting just putting them all in one file. But if I do this the page numbers and sections numbers wont change across the whole document.

Is there a way for me to change the fancy header data within the body in for each class date?

Here is my rough template

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[left=1.3cm,right=4.7cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=4.0cm,marginparwidth=3.4cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\newcommand{\mn}[1]{\marginnote{\footnotesize #1}}

\newcommand\BackgroundStructure{
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}

\setlength\fboxsep{0mm}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5mm} 
\put(10, 10){\fcolorbox{black}{blue!10}{\framebox(155,247){}}}
\put(165, 10){\fcolorbox{black}{blue!10}{\framebox(37,247){}}}
\put(10, 262){\fcolorbox{black}{white!10}{\framebox(192, 25){}}}
\put(137, 265){\includegraphics[height=18mm,keepaspectratio]{rit_black_no_bar}}
}

\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{l r | l r}
\textbf{Class Name} & cName & \textbf{Class Num} & cNum  \\
\textbf{Page} & \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}& \textbf{Note} & cClass/tClass \\
\textbf{Class Date}& cDate & \textbf{Updated} & \today \\
\textbf{Author} & my name & \textbf{Professor} & tName \\
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundStructure}
\include{className_date.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you just have all of the parameters defined in your header given by macros that defined in each include file to required values?

Comment: Do you think you could give an example. I've never actually used macros sadly

Comment: I created a new fancyhdr style, then in the body i renewcommand

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using a macro and custom page style

In header:

```
\newcommand{\test}{Place Holder Text}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{l r | l r}
\textbf{Class Name} & \test & \textbf{Class Num} & cNum  \\
\textbf{Page} & \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}& \textbf{Note} & cClass/tClass \\
\textbf{Class Date}& cDate & \textbf{Updated} & \today \\
\textbf{Author} & my name & \textbf{Professor} & tName \\
\end{tabular}}
}
```

In body:

```
\renewcommand{\test}{Class Name}
    \pagestyle{mystyle}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put something like:

```
\newcommand\ClassName{ClassName}
\newcommand\ClassNum{ClassNum}
\newcommand\ClassDate{ClassDate}
\newcommand\ClassProf{ClassProf}

\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{l r | l r}
\textbf{Class Name} & \ClassName & \textbf{Class Num} & \ClassNum  \\
\textbf{Page} & \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}& \textbf{Note} & cClass/tClass \\
\textbf{Class Date}& \ClassDate & \textbf{Updated} & \today \\
\textbf{Author} & my name & \textbf{Professor} & \ClassProf \\
\end{tabular}}
```

in your main file and then

```
\renewcommand\ClassName{Class Two}
\renewcommand\ClassNum{Class II}
\renewcommand\ClassDate{Tuesday}
\renewcommand\ClassProf{Prof Two}
```

into each of your class files.